# Number of lines text needs at compile time

Tags: android, android-layout

Friends,

I have 3 text views in a `LinearLayout` which has a bounded width of `300dp`. Each text view has a `layout_weight` of 1 so the screen  will be divided evenly among the three `TextViews`.

> [text view 1][text view 2][text view 3]

Most of the time the text fits in one line in each of the TextView but there are some occasion  when it does not. Is there any way I could determine that the Text will need two lines and set the number of lines parameter of the TextView to 2?

If one of the TextViews needs 2 lines than all three TextViews should be set to two lines

Comment: If you do not specify `android:lines` and the TextView's height is set to `wrap_content`, it should automatically adjust to multiple lines. Is this not quite what you require?

Comment: Or just set `android:lines="2"` once and for all.

Comment: I do not specify android:lines. The height is set to "wrap_content". The problem is that TextView1 could require 2 lines but TextView2 and TextView3 will not. However even if one of them requires 2 lines I want to set all TextViews to android:lines = 2

Comment: setting android:lines=2 is something I don not want unless the text to appear will require 2 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes- TextView has a [`getLineCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29) method that will tell you how many lines of text are the TextView.

Unfortunately there's a caveat- the TextView must be layed out and measured before this method works properly.

If you are setting the text dynamically (e.g. via `setText()`), then you will need to create a callback for when the layout pass happens like so:

```
mTextView1.getViewTreeObserver()
    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (mTextView1.getLineCount() > 1) { // or textView2, etc.
                // Adjust all text view heights
            }
        }
    });
```